# ASP.NET redirect user based on role

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect, authentication

I want the app to redirect a user to a different home page depending on their role. Its currently working for 2 users using the following IF?

```
    If Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("Staff") = True Then
        Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx")
    ElseIf Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("HR") = False Then
        Response.Redirect("~/HR\HRCompanyNavigation.aspx")
    End If
```

How can I get this to work for more than 2 user roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? This might work for simpler scenarios. But you should have in mind that this is a weak construct if users has multiple roles.

```
If Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("Staff") = True Then
            Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx")
        ElseIf Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("HR") = True Then
            Response.Redirect("~/HR\HRCompanyNavigation.aspx")
        ElseIf Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("ThirdRole") = True Then
            Response.Redirect("~/ThirdFolder\ThirdPage.aspx")
    End If
```

Comment: I am using Login Control and I don't know where do I need to put that code to redirect to different page based on Roles ... Is it under Login1_Authenticate method ?